# Requesting advice for "visually" filter a collection in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm writing a basic ShoppingCart App as my first ember.js application. The first feature is to filter products based on a keyword. The entire product catalog is displayed first:
https://skitch.com/nicholas.henry/gw5js/online-store-all-products-active

And when a keyword is clicked the products are filtered (opacity is set to 0.2):
https://skitch.com/nicholas.henry/gw5kn/online-store-selected-products

I have this feature working, but am looking for some design advice/review. You can try it out at: http://shoppingcart-js.heroku.com/

I am doing this using a binding on a property 'isActive' on the product model, but this doesn't seem quite right to me. It feels like I'm missing another object to track this property, as this is really a view property, not a model one. The code is here:

https://github.com/nicholasjhenry/shoppingcart.js/blob/95ffd2e3eb5aaf2e9e6c44c71f19b06c29c84a93/site/javascripts/application.js

I would greatly appreciate anyone take a look and make a recommendation to help me implement this feature with a better design. Thank you.